# Can we deploy Nextjs app in vercel for production? Can it handle heavy trafiic?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am new to Nextjs. I need to deploy Nextjs app to production. Can vercel handle heavy traffic?

Or we need to use other platforms like AWS, GCP for deployment?

Please hep me out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can deploy Next.js to Vercel.

Vercel made Next.js, and the platform is designed to host Next.js at scale.

https://vercel.com/solutions/nextjs

Under the hood, Vercel actually deploys your site on AWS and GCP, so you get as much scalability as you would on those other platforms. I've used Vercel for many months now and have never had an issue with scalability. Not affiliated with them at all outside of being a customer.